# C# - regex array

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it possible to make array of regex.

```
Regex[] rgx = {@" ", @" ", @" "};
```

instead of doing

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@" ")
Regex rgx1 = new Regex(@" ");
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(@" ");
```

I have been trying to look on google but I couldn't find anything about this question...

Thank you :)

Comment: `Regex[] rgx = {new Regex(@" "), new Regex(@" "), new Regex(@" ")};`

Comment: See [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) on Microsoft Docs for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to use "OR" condition in regex?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop to test every word as you can put them all into one regular expression (separated by the `|` character) and let the regex engine look for any of them all at once.  You could do that like this:

```
function regtest(txt){
    var unforgivable = [
        "reg1",
        "reg2",
        "reg3",
        "reg4"
    ];
    var re = new Regex(unforgivable.join("|"), "i");
    return re.test(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq could be handy here (as for soo many other things):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> scriptcs
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
> var rgx = new []{@" ", @" ", @" "}.Select(s=>new Regex(s));
```